# How to get object from database using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to check if user exists in database by username with SQL query using ADO.NET in ASP.NET WebAPI.

Like in Entity there is Any() call that does job.

```
private async Task<bool> UserExists(string username)
{
 return await context.Contacts.AnyAsync(x => x.UserId == username.ToLower());
}

if (await UserExists(createUserDto.Username)) 
     return BadRequest("Username is taken");
```

I want to do the same job but manually with SQL query and to store that object in var user and finally ask if there is a user in DB...(and to do other coding with that user).

I am passing CreateUserDtO which I want to create,  to function with property string userId further in the body of getUserByUserName. UserId is string.

```
var user = await accountRepository.GetUserById(createUserDto.UserId);
```

I am opening connection, executing query, commit/rollback transaction and closing connection in GetUserById(string username). I just want to know how my query should be look like that returns object of that user.

```
public Task<bool> GetUserById(string username)
        {
            int result = 0;
            bool success = false;
            string usernameCheck = username.ToLower();

            try
            {
                OpenConnection();
                BeginTransaction();

                string query = "...";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection, transaction);
                result = "..."
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ = log.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message + "\nStackTrace : " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    CommitTransaction();
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RollbackTransaction();
                }
                CloseConnection();
            }

            return success;
        }
```

}

Is that possible?

Comment: You say SQL, but I see no SQL above. Are you sure you want an SQL _language_ answer?

Comment: It sounds like you need an ADO.NET tutorial, not just a query. ADO.NET returns row results, not objects. This code has severe bugs already and it doesn't even execute any query

Comment: For example, connections are meant to be short-lived. Retrieving a single row doesn't need transactions at all. This code will leak connections and cause extensive blocking

Comment: Check [Basics of ADO.NET](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/basics/ado-net/) to see how ADO.NET works. *After* you do that check [Basics of Dapper](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/basics/dapper/) to see how this can be simplified

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that the SQL will vary by RDBMS; let's use SQL Server, for example; the *query* you want is probably:

```sql
select count(1)
from Users
where UserId = @userId
```

which will return the number of matching records, where `@userId` is the parameter we want. Now; the ADO.NET raw API is *complex* - honestly, your best bet may be to use either a raw SQL API on `context.Something`, or a tool like Dapper; for example, with Dapper:

```cs
using var connection = OpenConnection();

var count = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<int>(@"
select count(1)
from Users
where UserId = @userId", new { userId = username.ToLower() });

return count != 0;
```

Note that here I'm preserving the `ToLower()` semantics at the call site; everything in the `new {...}` is the parameters for Dapper pass to ADO.NET.

You can *also* do something similar with `exists` in SQL, if that is preferable; or you could `select top 1 UserId` and use `QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<string>()`, and check it against `null` (the default if nothing is returned). This last approach has the advantage of also fetching the case-corrected version from the database, if you need it.